# Excel work timetracking sheet with graphs that show time spent per task/person

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation, charts

I'm trying to make an Excel sheet that has a table containing the start time of a task, the end time, time spent on that task, a description and with who.

I got the table part down, as well as the automatic calculation of time spent on the task. But I'd really like to have a graph that shows how much time has been spent on each person in the table. If possible I'd also like to assign multiple people to one task and have the graph split it automatically.

Thanks a lot in advance and if anything is not clear enough I'd like to elaborate on it!

Comment: Welcome to SU.  To get a good answer you'll need to provide more info about your problem (e.g. is the chart organized by person or task, shown in total units or percent, etc...).  Even a sketch of your final output would be helpful.  Also, please include what you've already tried and why that didn't work.  For a starting point, you should try summarizing your table data in a pivot table, and then chart the results of the pivot.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.